# Hand over Sessionvariable

Tags: php, session, session-variables

got a question.
I have 3 session variables:

```
$_SESSION['div1'] = 5
$_SESSION['div2'] = 10
$_SESSION['div3'] = 18
```

Now i want to hand over the value from `$_SESSION['div2']` to `$_SESSION['div1']`

So i write:

```
$_SESSION['div1'] = $_SESSION['div2'];
```

So if i output `$_SESSION['div1']` it works and it shows: 10.

But then i want to hand over the value from `$_SESSION['div3']` to `$_SESSION['div2']`.

I write:

```
$_SESSION['div2'] = $_SESSION['div3'];
```

But then every variable got the value from $_SESSION['div3'].
So if i output everything i get:

```
$_SESSION['div1'] = 18
$_SESSION['div2'] = 18
$_SESSION['div3'] = 18
```

Why is this so?
Is this because of the session and it don't works chronologically?

I tried it with unset():

```
$_SESSION['div1'] = $_SESSION['div2'];
unset($_SESSION['div2']);
$_SESSION['div2'] = $_SESSION['div3'];
```

But it still don't worked.

Anyone an idea how to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Values are passed on by reference. So $_SESSION['div1'] does not hold the value of $_SESSION['div2'] but a reference to it. When you change $_SESSION['div2'] then $_SESSION['div1'] also changes as it is reading from the same memory spot.

Comment: Thank you very much!
Understand now how this works.
Question. How can i solve it if i want to get the value from div3 to div2?
Any idea?

Comment: It should probably work when you use another (not session) variable, set its value to `$_SESSION['div2']`, then `unset` that session div2 variable, then do the other value switch with div2 and div3. Keep in mind if div3 changes, div2 will change too. It is not clear why you want this switch, maybe you need to rethink your strategy.